# Jump to certain element using owl.carousel.js in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, owl-carousel

I'm using plugin for owl.carousel.js for Vue - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-owl-carousel.

I want to open a certain slide in the carousel, but it seems like this plugin doesn't provide an ability to do it in a Vue-way. (Yes. I know that even if it would provide it - there still be used a JQuery under the hood).

Is there any way to call native plugin's methods without changing a plugin?